# Do I need to add Bundler itself to the Gemfile?

Tags: ruby, dependencies, bundler

When I'm using Bundler, do I need to list itself as a dependency in my Gemfile? After all, there are places in my code where I require it. For instance, when I'm doing the Bundler setup: `require "bundler/setup"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You could try but first you have to lift yourself off the ground by your bootlaces.